# RestKit putObject not working with Rails model

Tags: objective-c, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, restkit, sunspot-solr

I am messing around with Restkit in iOS and rails. I cannot for the life of me figure out why my code is not working. Basically I have a ProfileModel class in iOS and I setup the object mapping for it and call the methods as below:

```
-(IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender
{ 
NSLog(@"Editprofile save button clicked");

RKObjectMapping *objectmappingSerialProfile = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ProfileModel class]];

[objectmappingSerialProfile mapKeyPath:@"location" toAttribute:@"country"];
[objectmappingSerialProfile mapKeyPath:@"descriptionText" toAttribute:@"description"];
[objectmappingSerialProfile mapKeyPath:@"facebookID" toAttribute:@"facebook"];
[objectmappingSerialProfile mapKeyPath:@"username" toAttribute:@"name"];
[objectmappingSerialProfile mapKeyPath:@"twitterID" toAttribute:@"twittername"];
[objectmappingSerialProfile mapKeyPath:@"website" toAttribute:@"website"];

NSDictionary *authTokenParam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:@"auth_token",@"pb9mp459iUj6NnmPk5C2", nil];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[ProfileModel class] toResourcePath:[@"/modifyProfile.json" appendQueryParams:authTokenParam] forMethod:RKRequestMethodPUT];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:objectmappingSerialProfile forClass:[ProfileModel class]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] putObject:self.navProfile delegate:nil];

}
```

When I run this code I get the following error message in the debugger window in Xcode

```
2012-03-20 23:51:22.815 Someprogram[3684:fe03] Editprofile save button clicked
2012-03-20 23:51:22.921 Someprogram[3684:fe03] W     restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:241 Unable to find parser for MIME Type 'text/html'
2012-03-20 23:51:22.921 Someprogram[3684:fe03] W     restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:262 Encountered unexpected response with status code: 500 (MIME Type: text/html)
```

I use rails 0.9.3 and my response in the rails window is as follows

```
 Started PUT "/modifyProfile.json?auth_token=pb9mp459iUj6NnmPk5C2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-20 23:51:22 +0000
Processing by ProfilesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"country"=>"earth2", "name"=>"AdiUpdated2", "twittername"=>"abc", "website"=>"hmmm", "description"=>"abcc", "facebook"=>"abcd", "auth_token"=>"pb9mp459iUj6NnmPk5C2", "profile"=>{"name"=>"AdiUpdated2", "description"=>"abcc", "twittername"=>"abc", "facebook"=>"abcd", "website"=>"hmmm", "country"=>"earth2"}}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 9 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SOLR Request (2.2ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007fc565d65f88> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><add><doc><field name="id">User 9</field><field name="type">User</field><field name="type">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name="class_name">User</field></doc></add>, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: } ]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22ms

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
  rsolr (1.0.7) lib/rsolr/connection.rb:15:in `execute'
  sunspot_rails (1.3.0) lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:14:in `block in execute_with_as_instrumentation'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  sunspot_rails (1.3.0) lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:12:in `execute_with_as_instrumentation'
  rsolr (1.0.7) lib/rsolr/client.rb:166:in `execute'
  rsolr (1.0.7) lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
  (eval):2:in `post'
  rsolr (1.0.7) lib/rsolr/client.rb:67:in `update'
  rsolr (1.0.7) lib/rsolr/client.rb:87:in `add'
  sunspot (1.3.0) lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:101:in `add_documents'
  sunspot (1.3.0) lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:26:in `add'
  sunspot (1.3.0) lib/sunspot/session.rb:91:in `index'
  sunspot (1.3.0) lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `index'
  sunspot (1.3.0) lib/sunspot.rb:184:in `index'
  sunspot_rails (1.3.0) lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:372:in `solr_index'
  sunspot_rails (1.3.0) lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:470:in `perform_index_tasks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `_run__3891665525441134440__save__2817329553089450813__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:190:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
  devise (2.0.4) lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb:58:in `forget_me!'
  devise (2.0.4) lib/devise/controllers/rememberable.rb:32:in `forget_me'
  devise (2.0.4) lib/devise/hooks/forgetable.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/hooks.rb:14:in `call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/hooks.rb:14:in `block in _run_callbacks'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/hooks.rb:9:in `each'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/hooks.rb:9:in `_run_callbacks'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:53:in `_run_callbacks'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/proxy.rb:243:in `block in logout'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/proxy.rb:241:in `each'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/proxy.rb:241:in `logout'
  devise (2.0.4) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:156:in `sign_out_all_scopes'
  devise (2.0.4) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:261:in `handle_unverified_request'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:78:in `verify_authenticity_token'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__1101336661489218557__process_action__1327857175712471554__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
  journey (1.0.1) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.1) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.1) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__632645031902289657__call__2817329553089450813__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/Adi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/Adi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/Adi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/Adi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (6.9ms)
```

However, if I use a program called RESTClient on mac to execute the same PUT request. It works fine and the Rails response in the window is:

```
Started PUT "/modifyProfile.json?auth_token=pb9mp459iUj6NnmPk5C2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-21 00:02:57 +0000
Processing by ProfilesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"country"=>"earth22", "description"=>"abcc", "twittername"=>"abc", "facebook"=>"abcd", "website"=>"hmmm", "name"=>"AdiUpdated2", "auth_token"=>"pb9mp459iUj6NnmPk5C2", "profile"=>{"name"=>"AdiUpdated2", "description"=>"abcc", "twittername"=>"abc", "facebook"=>"abcd", "website"=>"hmmm", "country"=>"earth22"}}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = 'pb9mp459iUj6NnmPk5C2' LIMIT 1
  Profile Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = 9 LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered profiles/update.json.rabl (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 4.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

The only difference I am seeing is something to do with sunspot solr which is creating some sort of an issue. But the request code seems to be the same so why is Rails responding differently to this?? Can anyone please help?

Do apologize about the long lines of code but not sure what you guys may want to look at to see what I am I doing wrong??

Many thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooookkk. This is rather embarrassing.  But posting this if anyone faces the same issue somewhere down the line.

The issue occurs as I forgot to turn on the Solr server. Ooops. Once the server is up and running, it works.

But I would still like to understand why is this an issue when running via Restkit and not through a RESTClient program.